# iphone / ipad - Compile three20 under xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, three20

anyone successfully compiled three20 under XCode 4?

I tried, and changed all Base SDK to latest 4.2, but there is alway a error:

error: There is no SDK with the name or path '..../three20/src/Three20Core/iphoneos4.0'

in Three20UICommon and its Unit tests.

Anyone has a clue about this?

Also, in Xcode 3, I know I can let all UnitTests not to be compiled by deselecting the bulleye for UnitTests. How can I do it in XCode 4?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow this step to integrate three20, u will b thru

https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/README.mdown

Answer (score 1):

I tried the manual steps and failed. The added Three20 project files can not be opened like they used to in an xcode3 project.

Instead I've started from an existing xcode3 project which already works with Three20 (try one of the samples) and started to use it in xcode4. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

Three20 supports Xcode 4 now. Check this out http://three20.info/article/2011-03-10-Xcode4-Support.